# No output when calling a stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

Is there any mistake in my SQL code? The procedure is apparently created, there's no error, but when I call it with `CALL user_orders(10)` I get no rows. The query itself is valid: if I execute it on its own (not as a procedure), I get the rows I expect. It's PostgreSQL

In summary, this outputs no rows:

```sql
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE user_orders(lim INTEGER)
BEGIN ATOMIC
SELECT u.name, o.product, o.price,
o.quantity, (o.quantity * o.price) AS total 
FROM users AS u
JOIN orders AS o
ON u.id = o.user_id
LIMIT lim;
end;
```

```sql
CALL user_orders(10);
```

But this *does* output rows:

```sql
SELECT u.name, o.product, o.price,
o.quantity, (o.quantity * o.price) AS total 
FROM users AS u
JOIN orders AS o
ON u.id = o.user_id
LIMIT 10;
```

I tried this as well:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE user_orders(lim INTEGER)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
SELECT u.name, o.product, o.price,
o.quantity, (o.quantity * o.price) AS total 
FROM users AS u
JOIN orders AS o
ON u.id = o.user_id
LIMIT lim;
$$;
```

I believe my code is in line with the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html)

What's wrong?

[db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/qyEN3A2k)

Answer (score 2):

It is in the nature of a procedure not to return results. If you want results, write a function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION user_orders(lim INTEGER)
   RETURNS TABLE (name text, product text, price numeric, quantity integer, total numeric)
RETURN u.name, o.product, o.price,
o.quantity, (o.quantity * o.price) AS total 
FROM users AS u
...;
```

I guessed the result data types; use the correct ones.

Comment: Thank you! But if a procedure is a `SELECT`, shouldn't it perform a `SELECT` (which involves providing some output)

Comment: It does perform a `SELECT`, but that result is lost. How should it pass the result to the caller?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe In fairness, this does work in most other DBMSs.

Comment: @Charlieface Not in Oracle, for one. Perhaps in Microsoft SQL Server (I don't know), but I wouldn't consider that "most DBMSs". Perhaps there is also a confusion that arises because many people use the word "stored procedure" when they talk about a function.

Comment: SQL Server, MySQL, MariaDB, DB2 all can do this to my knowledge. Maybe not most, certainly some.

Comment: As someone still very much learning PostgreSQL but coming from a SQL Server background, yeah, I too was shocked that "stored procedure" didn't mean the same thing. "Function" doesn't mean the same thing either. Procs are a different critter. Functions are what you, and I, think of as procs.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe for example, you can have a void function in Java that prints something to the standard output. I expected a similar effect in PostgreSQL

Comment: There is no "standard output" on the database server. You can send a message to the client with `RAISE NOTICE` or `RAISE INFO` in a function, but that will not be the return value of the function (just like in Java).